# Geoprocessing web service not writing out all files for .shp

Tags: python, shapefile, geoprocessing, arccatalog

I created a Python script, run by a toolbox. I am using Python shapefile to generate a point shapefile. If I run the tool locally (i.e. on the desktop) it works great. Shp, shx and dbf all writen out as expected and the points are valid.

Once I share the geoprocessing script as a service, and then run the tool via an ArcGIS server connection on a remote PC, the only file that writes out is the .shp file. And of course without the .shx and .dbf the .shp file can't be used.

Any ideas on why once the geoprocessing script runs server side, all the files aren't generating for Python library Shapefile?

Any other ideas on how to simply write out a point shapefile using Python?

I know typically a code snippet, is desired, but the code runs locally it's only server side where there is an issue writing the files to a client via, ArcCatalog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up zipping up the files and then outputting them. this worked like a charm. I think that was happening is that on output the only file being sent from server, was the .shp file. Once they are zipped up then the .zip gets sent but that has all the files compressed. My conclusion is that zipping is the only way to do server side geoprocessing with file out as a parameter.

So in my geoprocessing script I added in this code:

def zipws(path, zip, keep):
    path = os.path.normpath(path)
    # os.walk visits every subdirectory, returning a 3-tuple
    #  of directory name, subdirectories in it, and filenames
    #  in it.
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
        # Iterate over every filename
        for file in filenames:
            # Ignore .lock files
            if not file.endswith('.lock'):
                #gp.AddMessage("Adding %s..." % os.path.join(path, dirpath, file))
                try:
                    if keep:
                        zip.write(os.path.join(dirpath, file),
                        os.path.join(os.path.basename(path), os.path.join(dirpath, file)[len(path)+len(os.sep):]))
                    else:
                        zip.write(os.path.join(dirpath, file),
                        os.path.join(dirpath[len(path):], file))

```
            except Exception as e:
                #Message "    Error adding %s: %s"
                gp.AddWarning(get_ID_message(86134) % (file, e[0]))
return None
```

try:
        zip = zipfile.ZipFile(outzip, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        zipws(unicode(folder), zip, "CONTENTS_ONLY")
        zip.close()
except RuntimeError:
        # Delete zip file if exists
        if os.path.exists(outzip):
            os.unlink(outzip)
        zip = zipfile.ZipFile(outzip, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_STORED)
        zipws(unicode(folder), zip, "CONTENTS_ONLY")
        zip.close()
        #Message"  Unable to compress zip file contents."
        gp.AddWarning(get_ID_message(86133))